# Need help solving jQuery issue with targeting specific element within structure

Tags: jquery

I have a basic setup that is working but for one issue I am struggling with.

I have multiple videos (using just 2 for testing) that when each is hovered over, it will play. So far, so good. I also have a div overlay with a play button (.tnplay) that is supposed to get hidden on rollover. The issue is the way I am trying to hide the div.tnplay on rollover. I need to hide just the one on the target video and right now, all are being hidden, since they are the same class.

How would I go about targeting just the .tnplay div related to the specific video?
This is the jQuery I am struggling with:

```
var tn = $(".tnplay");
var v = $(".thevideo");
//check if video is ready to play
$(v).on('canplay', function() {
  $(v).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).get(0).play();
    $(tn).hide();
  })
  .mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).get(0).pause();
    $(tn).show();
    $(this).get(0).currentTime=0;
  })
});
```

Here is my working example: https://codepen.io/darksoundlab/pen/XWJZeRX

Thanks for any help. You all are awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace you this line of code:

```
$(tn).hide();
```

with this:

```
$(this).parents(".vidwrapper").find(".tnplay").hide();
```

Comment: This was the direction I was trying to go but I wasn't quite understanding the parent, parents relationship and how to target the specific element. I see this answer is fairly simpl and straight forward once I see the syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are selecting all elements and you are triggering the hide and show on every element using JS.

I recommend to use CSS instead of JS to show and hide the overlay:

Javascript:

```
var tn = $(".tnplay");
var v = $(".thevideo");
//check if video is ready to play
$(v).on('canplay', function() {
  $(tn).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).get(0).play();
  })
  .mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).get(0).pause();
    $(this).get(0).currentTime=0;
  })
});
```

CSS:

```
.tnplay {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tnplay:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

And the play/pause functionality depends on the hover on the overlay instead of the video (the overlay will catch the event instead of the video itself)

Also you can add some CSS animation for the transition.

Answer (score 0):

This is a faster and quicker solution as it will find only closest "tnplay" class and hide it.

```
var tn = $(".tnplay");
var v = $(".thevideo");
//check if video is ready to play
$(v).on('canplay', function(){
  $(v).mouseenter(function(){
   //select only one tnplay
      $(this).get(0).play();
      $(this).closest('.vidwrapper').find('.tnplay').hide();
     }).mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).get(0).pause();
      $(tn).show();
     $(this).get(0).currentTime=0;
   })
});
```